# Select query problem not data like i want

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `father` and `grand_father`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS father (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    father_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grand_father (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    father_id int(6) NOT NULL,
    grand_father_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO father (id, father_name) VALUES
  ('1','Abid'),
  ('2','Hasan'),
  ('3','Jabed');
INSERT INTO grand_father (id, father_id,grand_father_name) VALUES
  ('1','1','Jon'),
  ('2','1','James'),
  ('3','2','Jakir'),
  ('4','2','Jamir'),
  ('5','3','Tom');

  select f.father_name,g.grand_father_name
from grand_father g
left join father f
on g.father_id = f.id;

+-------------+-------------------+
| father_name | grand_father_name |
+-------------+-------------------+
| Abid        | Jon               |
| Abid        | James             |
| Hasan       | Jakir             |
| Hasan       | Jamir             |
| Jabed       | Tom               |
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Code link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8be4c/3
Query Problem

I want like this result:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| father_name  | grand_father_name |
+--------------+-------------------+
|   Abid       | Jon               |
|              | James             |
+--------------+-------------------+
|   Abid       | Jon               |
|              | James             |
+--------------+-------------------+
|   Jabed      | Tom               |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

It's is possible or not ?
How can i get like this result.
I try :

```
select f.father_name, g.grand_father_name 
from grand_father g 
left join father f 
  on g.father_id = f.id
```

Comment: That should be done via Presentation layer.

Comment: *"That should be done via Presentation layer. "* [Grouping and Merging array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058241/grouping-and-merging-array-in-php)  because the question was tagged with `PHP` also

Comment: it's possible i want like this result @YogeshSharma

Answer (score 1):

use `group_concat()`

```
select f.father_name,group_concat(g.grand_father_name SEPARATOR '\r\n')
from grand_father g
left join father f
on g.father_id = f.id
group by f.father_name
```

Comment: Topicstarter you could also use a separator if you need lines `GROUP_CONCAT(g.grand_father_name SEPARATOR '\r\n')` or with html `GROUP_CONCAT(g.grand_father_name SEPARATOR '<br />')`,  But you ideally should do this in the application layer (the view when working with MVC frameworks)

Comment: Topicstarter, you should take the advice provided in the first comment after your question

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, everyone has a grandfather.  In which case:

```
select f.father_name,
       group_concat(g.grand_father_name) as grand_fathers
from father f join
     grand_father g
     on g.father_id = f.id
group by f.father_name;
```

I prefer the default separate of a comma, but you can change that.

If you want all fathers, even those with no grand father, then use a `left join` instead.