# Combine multidimential array columns by common value

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have the following array which represents a working schedule:

```
    Array
    (
        ...,
        [1] => Array
            (
                [TIME] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [FROM] => 10:00
                                [TO] => 20:00
                            )
                    )
                [DAYS] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 5
                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [TIME] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [FROM] => 22:00
                                [TO] => 00:00
                            )
                    )
                [DAYS] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 5
                    )
            )
    )
```

What I would like to do is to combine (or merge?) array columns if `DAYS` key is common so the result would look like this:

```
    Array
    (
        ...,
        [1] => Array
            (
                [TIME] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [FROM] => 10:00
                                [TO] => 20:00
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [FROM] => 22:00
                                [TO] => 00:00
                            )
                    )
                [DAYS] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 5
                    )
            )
    )
```

I used to try `array_merge()` and `array_combine()` functions but they didn't work as I thought they should.

Comment: Why not use a simple foreach loop and have a hashmap, get days as key, check if the key exists or not, if it doesn't then create it with the array and if does exists merge the time values? Also please keep the input and output in a format which users can try/

Comment: @Adi can u please share an example? Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Group and merge subarray data based on one column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45834118/2943403) and [Group row data in a 3d array by a column and merge the subarray data in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27058241/2943403) -- specifically find ["Fringe Demo" and "Fringe Demo 2"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54293222/2943403)  ...If it had an upvoted answer, I could have hammered this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something I tried with your given input and output, assuming Days just has one value, correct?

```
$schedules = 
[
    [
        'TIME' => 
            [
                [
                    "FROM" => "10:00",
                    "TO" => "20:00"
                ]
            ],
        'DAYS' => [5]
    ],
    [
        'TIME' => 
            [
                [
                    "FROM" => "22:00",
                    "TO" => "00:00"
                ]
            ],
        'DAYS' => [5]
    ]
];
$hashmap = [];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
    $days = $schedule['DAYS'][0];
    if (!isset($hashmap[$days])) {
        $hashmap[$days] = $schedule;
    } else {
        $hashmap[$days]['TIME'] = array_merge($hashmap[$days]['TIME'], $schedule['TIME']);
    }
}
$hashmap = array_values($hashmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

As demonstrated in [Group and merge related subarray data in multidimensional array: Consolidate related taxonomy array settings to be used in a Wordpress query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76234252/2943403) (I could not use this page as a dupe target because there are no upvoted answers), Create references on the first encountered instance of the "identifying data", then push that reference (containing the first instance's data) into the result array.  For any subsequent encounters of the same "identifying data", push the new subset's data into the reference.  Because this technique modifies the original (instead of creating a new array), `unset()` (consume) the later encountered instances.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kb9kN))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
    $d = $schedule['DAYS'][0];
    if (!isset($ref[$d])) {
        $ref[$d] = $schedule;
        $result[] = &$ref[$d];
    } else {
         array_push($ref[$d]['TIME'], ...$schedule['TIME']);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Using `array_push()` merely appends the new data to the end of the indexed subarray instead of calling `array_merge()`.